# Desativar som navegador?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo um navegador em `c#` e nele tem um botão de desativar `áudio`. Esse botão mais especificamente desativaria qualquer áudio que toca-se no navegador como ver vídeos do `youtube` por exemplo e outro botão para ativar o áudio do navegador de novo.

Teria como fazer?
Abraços!

Comment: teoricamente sim, se o seu browser tiver como reproduzir sons, por exemplo quando vc assiste um vídeo no mozilla ou executa um audio, se vc abrir o controlador de áudio da maquina vera que quem reproduz o audio é o FlashPlayer e não o mozilla de fato, porem no google chrome ele mesmo quem reproduz o som

Comment: Bem, convenhamos que você dá pouquíssimas informações sobre como você está desenvolvendo isso, e assim fica difícil dar uma resposta que seja útil. O máximo que dá para fazer é dizer "Sim, daria. Boa sorte", mas isso seria uma resposta muito inútil. Portanto, tente colocar mais detalhes sobre o que você está fazendo em sua pergunta para que os colegas possam ter algo para embasar uma resposta legal.

Comment: Concordo com o @VictorStafusa no entanto votei para reabrir pois existe uma resposta e gostaria de colaborar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Dei o meu voto para reabrir. Espero que tenha uma excelente resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa cara a ameaça me fez tremer, prometo que vou tentar fazer o melhor hehehe. Obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento kkk, fica frio, isso não foi uma ameaça. Foi mais um voto de "boa sorte".

Comment: @VictorStafusa é o que a máfia italo-americana falava pros delatores antes de levar eles naqueles passeios de barco (sem volta) hehehehe, brincadeiras a parte então a resposta na verdade esta no SOen e parece que foi bem aceita por lá e a pergunta é bem simples igual a esta, eu pretendo apenas trazer o que tem lá pro português ;)

Comment: @VictorStafusa parece que recusaram a abrir a pergunta... tentar de novo, qualquer coisa vou fazer uma nova pergunta.